# Rewrite specific URL to different directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im trying to redirect this,

example.com/**slide?page=4** to example.com/**slide/issue43?page=4**

But it cannot effect other URL's like, example.com/**slide/issue57?page=4**

Im really stuck, these regular expressions are so weird. Here's the rewriterule that I've come up with,

```
This is not working    
RewriteRule ^slide?page(.*)$ http://example.com/slide/issue43?page=$1 [L,R=301]
```

I need to target '**slide?page=X**' specifically and have it redirect or point to '**slide/issue43?page=X**'

Comment: Ok so I think its the question marks that are screwing things up. Ive also changed the way it handles the page number to only use numbers. Here is what I'm using now. `RewriteRule ^slide?page=([0-9]+)$ /slide/issue12?page=$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Ok, I learned that in order for regular expressions to view a question marks as a literal character you have to put a backslash before it. Using this now `RewriteRule ^slide\?page=([0-9]+)$ /slide/issue12\?page=$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Oh well, I didnt even need to use the backslashes for the question marks. Still good to know though! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/slide$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /slide/issue57?page=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It worked! In your code I just changed issue57 to issue43 since I need it to point to issue43. Its working flawlessly and is not causing problems with other pages. This is a PERFECT SOLUTION, I learned a lot about conditions & queries inside of regex. Thank you sooo much :-)